# Inserting data into a SharePoint list using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, sharepoint

I have the vba script below that I am trying to insert a record into a sharepoint list. However I encounter the error:

> Cannot update 'Title'; field not updateable.

at the line `conn.Execute strSQL`. The DELETE and SELECT works fine.

Any idea please.

```
Sub ConnectToSharePointList()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strConn As String
    
    ' Set the connection string
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=2;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=" & _
               "https://tenaname.sharepoint.com/sites/MySiteName/;LIST=" & _
               "{c25c3996-897a-482f-ae17-d57d4fe219b5};"
    
    ' Create a new connection object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    ' Open the connection
    conn.Open strConn
    
    ' Prepare Insert Sql statement
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO lst_requested_orders (Title,supplier,requested_date,quantity) VALUES ('Test','CHEP','2024-01-25',300)"
    
    ' Insert a new record
    conn.Execute strSQL
    
    ' Close the connection
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Title` column seems to be handled differently from the other columns as described [here](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/remove-sharepoint-online-title-column/).

Comment: Even if i skip the Title field (not a required field) the error will now be on the supplier field.

Comment: FYI the list GUID from the list's "settings" page is the one you want - it's different from the GUID you might see when viewing the list.

Comment: And may be try `conn.Execute strSQL, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic`

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. Apparently, it has to do with the structure or configuration of the SharePoint list. I'll do a further research. Thank you